# Java GUIs, JFrames, and Dialogs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I read that you shouldn't `.show()` frames on the main thread to avoid deadlock, is this a real problem. Should this always be avoided? Also once you display any sort of dialog box, such as a ProgressMonitorInputStream, even if it closes and is done, must you still call `System.exit()` to kill the app? What about a JDialog?

Comment: *"I read that you shouldn't `.show()` frames.."*  Since 1.5 we should [`setVisible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I read that you shouldn't .show() frames on the main thread to avoid deadlock

It'd stop reading that book/post/webpage.

To address your first point:

I think you may be missing some points.

All UI code **MUST** be executed on the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT), this includes UI components that aren't even on the screen yet.

You should **NOT** perform time consuming tasks one the EDT as this will prevent the screen from been updated and make your application non-responsive, which users really, really hate.

Time consuming tasks should be performed in there own Thread (this is actually an entirely different topic), using some thing like [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)/[andWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to resync/update the UI.

```
public class BackgroundTask implements Runnable { // extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < noQueries; i++) {
            runDatabaseQuery(i);
            updateProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void updateProgress(final int queryNo) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statusLabel.setText("Query: " + queryNo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

To address your second point:

Yes and no.  The `JFrame` class provides a [defaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) which you can use to terminate the main application.

However, if all you ever display is `JDialog` or other type of window, yes, you will need to call `System.exit` in order to terminate the JVM.

Where it's supported, you can use a [WindowListener.windowClosed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) event to monitor when you window is closed and take appropriate action.

Comment: To improve your answer, you can add a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() and invokeAndWait() example :)

Comment: @zip You're a hard task master my friend ;)

Comment: So I should invoke the show() on the EDT? Even though it,s just displaying the frame? Can I have the frame display itself as well?

Comment: Would having the frame display it self in its constructor be safe as well?

Comment: So long as the constructor was called from within the EDT.  You can check by using [EventQueue.isDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#isDispatchThread%28%29)

Comment: If you're really eager, you can have a read through [Threads and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)

Comment: In a way invokeLater / invokeAndWait are opposites of SwingWorker (one is used to execute on EDT, one is used not to) - this seems glossed over in text. Still +1.

Comment: I might be nick picking, but I would say one CAN be executed on the EDT (invokeLater) and both can be called off the EDT. The main benefit of invokeAndWait is it's capable of returning a value (and pausing the running thread and till it returns) - but essentially the we're saying the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Closing the main `JFrame` in an application should have you calling System.exit();
However, you can make the main `JFrame` close the application itself:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Modal `JDialog`s are blocking the thread they are called from. However, this has advantages. When you depend on answer for the user in a `JDialog` for performing an action, you must wait for that.

Comment: `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`  Better to use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: Yes, depending on what you want the behavior of the application to be. If it is the main frame and you want to exit the app without asking the user to save the app data, you can use the EXIT one.

Comment: I that exact case, you can use the `DISPOSE` one.  BTW - An app, should only have one frame.